# Where does Compass look for files to import?

Tags: import, rubygems, compass-sass, sass

When writing an `@import` statement in an SCSS file how does Compass know where to look?

I don't think this has been answered very well and I'm unable to find anything in the documentation.

I've been browsing the folders for the various Ruby gems and at one point I thought that any folder called `stylesheets` got added to some list somewhere (but where??). This can't be the whole explanation, however, since I've also seen `@import`'s referencing files that are not inside such a folder. I also haven't been able to find any config files defining this inside the gems.

Where is this information located *or* how is it generated?

Answer (score 1):

From http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import:

> "Sass looks for other Sass files in the current directory, and the
>   Sass file directory under Rack, Rails, or Merb."

You can shortcut imports by keeping them alongside the importing file and naming them "_[filename].scss" Then import them with @import "[filename]"

Compass scss/sass files are on your gem path:

> gems/compass-[version]/frameworks/compass/

Comment: Thanks, but this cannot be the whole truth - SASS is also able to import files from other modules, e.g. `modular-scale` in the case of Foundation. There must be some registry on the Ruby side that specifies which directories in each gem contain SCSS.

Comment: I've never used Foundation, but if you install it on your gempath (e.g. gem install foundation or whatever) its libraries should be available for import in any compass project that shares the gempath.